How to set custom menu items active in top menu depending on URL visited (menu caching issues)?
When I add custom menu items to the top menu (where product categories are placed) they are not set as active or are always active, depending on logic I implement for checking active state, no matter the URL. The actual issue is caching, I guess.
So, how to set menu items active, depending on URL visited? So it would work the same way as with product categories?

In order to solve the caching issue, you should flag a menu item as 'active' via JS instead of PHP. To see how this is done in Magento Luma theme, check lib/web/mage/menu.js file. Look at methods _setActiveMenu() and _setActiveMenuForCategory(). The main idea is that when page is loaded you check current URL and find a link in menu with the same URL and add some 'active' class to it (or to the parent div).
